# HelloAndroid Program

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new to android sdk. I started with the HelloAndroid program. I followed all specified instructions, but to my surprise, the emulator is not diplaying the "Hello Android" text.

[image]

Instead the emulator looks like the one shown above(You can see "LogCat" at the bottom of the image).

The Console shows msgs like,

---

[2010-10-28 20:14:59 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2010-10-28 20:14:59 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2010-10-28 20:15:34 - HelloAndroid] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-10-28 20:15:34 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-10-28 20:15:35 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2010-10-28 20:16:13 - HelloAndroid] Success!
[2010-10-28 20:16:13 - HelloAndroid] Starting activity com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid on device 
[2010-10-28 20:16:18 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.helloandroid/.HelloAndroid }

---

After some 7 min, "request time failed" error message is thrown in "LogCat".

Can someone help, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "unlock" the emulator. Click and drag the green lock symbol to the right.

What your seeing is the screen that would appear if you had a physical android device and you pushed the power button to turn the screen on after the device had gone to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

If you launching the emulator for the first time, you have to unlock it, just like how you unlock your android phone ( using the mouse instead ).